# Getting a glReadPixels (err: 1282, description: b'invalid operation') using PyOpenGL on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, opengl, raspberry-pi, pyopengl

I am writing an application using PyOpenGL (Python 3.5) and am getting an OpenGL error. Specifically it is an error concerning glReadPixels (err: 1282, description = b'invalid operation'). See below:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenGL/GL/images.py", line 371, in glReadPixels
imageData
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenGL/error.py", line 232, in glCheckError
baseOperation = baseOperation,
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glReadPixels,
    cArguments = (
            0,
            0,
            1640,
            1232,
            GL_RGBA,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, ...,
    )
)
```

I have run the exact same program with zero issues on various laptops and desktops running different OS's (Mac OSX, OpenSUSE, Arch Linux ...) and have recently been porting it to the Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspbian Stretch). This is where the issue has occurred. The code being run is below...

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
glLineWidth(4)
self.vbo.bind()
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, self.vbo)
vertex_count = int(len(self.all_vertices) / 3)
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vertex_count)
self.vbo.unbind()
glDeleteBuffers(1, [self.vbo])
glDeleteBuffers(1, GLuint(self.vbo))

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

glPopMatrix()
glPopMatrix()
glFlush()

x, y, width, height = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
data = glReadPixels(x,
                    y,
                    width,
                    height,
                    GL_RGBA,
                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)

image = Image.frombytes("RGBA", (width, height), data)
image = image.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
data = None
image.save(output_file, 'PNG')
```

I create the VBO for each iteration in a different function:

```
    self.all_vertices = np.array(self.all_vertices, dtype='float32')

    size = ADT.arrayByteCount(self.all_vertices)

    self.vbo = glvbo.VBO(self.all_vertices,
                         usage=GL_STATIC_DRAW,
                         target=GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                         size=size)
```

What makes this error even more puzzling is that before the error occurs it has successfully run the above code in a loop ~25 times outputting 25 PNGs. I have no idea why but suddenly on the ~26th iteration of this loop it throws this glReadPixels error. At first I thought maybe it was a resources issue of the Pi, however checking with htop everything appears fine.

I would be most grateful if anyone could offer any suggestions!